# Getting all combination of array elements that form a given string

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I am stuck on this interview question.
Given a word **S** and an array of strings **A**. How to find all possible combinations of A elemnts that can form S.
example :

```
S = "hotday"
A = ["o","ho","h","tday"]
```

the possible combinations are : ("h"+"o"+"tday") and ("ho"+"tday").

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use backtracking. Here is some pseudo code:

```
def generateSolutions(unusedWords, usedWords, string, position):
    if position == string.length():
        print(usedWords)
    else:
         for word in unusedWords:
             if word is a prefix of string[position ... s.length() - 1]:
                 generateSolutions(unusedWords - word, usedWords + word, 
                                   string, position + word.length())

generateSolution(words, an empty list, input string, 0)
```

The idea is very simple: we can just pick an unused word that matches a prefix of the rest of the input string and keep generating all valid combinations recursively(I assume that we can use each word from the given list of words only once). This solution has an exponential time complexity, but is not possible to do much better in the worst case. For instance, if the given string is `abcdef...yz` and the list of words is `[a, b, c, ..., z, ab, cd, ..., yz]`, the number of such combinations is `2 ^ n / 2`, where `n` is the length of the given string.

Comment: Might be nice to have a [prefix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) of the elements of A. Then you can identify words that are a prefix of the string a bit faster.

Comment: @Kevin : how can I integrate the prefix tree in this solution?

Comment: @user199 When we need to find if a word is a prefix of string[position...], we can traverse a prefix tree instead of iterating over all words.

Comment: @ILoveCoding : I implementedyour solution in java (see code below), it works fine. But don't you think that there is not need to use Tries? i just used a method ; getPrefixes(S,pos) that generate a set of possible prefixes. I don't see how a Trie can improve this. Can you explain that point?

Comment: @user199 A trie can increase its performance. If there are no performance issues, there is no need for a trie.

Comment: @ILoveCoding : i think a trie is good for finding all substrings, not finding prefixes.

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate through all permutations of A and see which ones fit. Python sample implementation:

```
import itertools
S = "hotday"
A = ["o","ho","h","tday"]
for count in range(len(A)):
    for pieces in itertools.permutations(A, count):
        if "".join(pieces) == S:
            print pieces
```

Result:

```
('ho', 'tday')
('h', 'o', 'tday')
```

Yes, this is O(N!), but that's fine for the small `A` you've provided.

Comment: I won't deny that. But a slow algorithm is better than no algorithm ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is my java solution, it is the implementation of the pseudo code of "ILoveCoding" :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;


public class PossibleCombination {


    public static void printPossibleCombinations(String[] tab, String S)
    {
        ArrayList<String> used = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> notused = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(tab));
        printPossibleCombinations(used, notused, S,0);
    }

    private static void printPossibleCombinations(ArrayList<String> used,
            ArrayList<String> notused, String s,int pos) {
            if (pos == s.length())
            {                   System.out.println("Possible combinaiton : ");

                for(String e : used)
                {
                    System.out.print(e + " - ");
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
            HashSet<String> prefixes = getPossiblePrefixes(s,pos);
            for(String e : notused)
            {

                if (prefixes.contains(e))
                {
                    ArrayList<String> isused = new ArrayList<String>(used);
                    isused.add(e);
                    ArrayList<String> isnotused = new ArrayList<String>(notused);
                    isnotused.remove(e);
                    printPossibleCombinations(isused, isnotused,s, pos + e.length());
                }
            }

    }

    private static HashSet<String> getPossiblePrefixes(String s, int pos) {
        HashSet<String> prefixes = new HashSet<String>();
        for(int i = pos ; i<= s.length() ; i++)
        {
            prefixes.add(s.substring(pos,i));
        }
        return prefixes;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] tab = {"o","ho","h","tday"};
        String S = "hotday";
        printPossibleCombinations(tab, S);
    }
}
```